# Why F# currying "flattens" function type?

Tags: f#

The following function:

```
let twoInputs x y =
    let sum = x + y
    let product a = sum * a
    product
```

Has the type:

```
val twoInputs : x:int -> y:int -> (int -> int)
```

That's perfectly reasonable, I see why it's coming. But why this function:

```
let oneInput = twoInputs 1
```

is of type `val oneInput : (int -> int -> int)` ?

Shouldn't it be `int -> (int -> int)` ?

Also, I think the functions above should comply with [Associative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property), so there should be no differences between `int -> int -> (int -> int)` and `int -> int -> int -> int`. If so, why not just specify the latter as the function type for `twoInputs`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parentheses mean "value of type FsharpFunc<_>", while the absence of parentheses means "true CLR method". In your example, `twoInput` is compiled to a true CLR method, but returns a value of type `FSharpFunc<_>`, hence its type. But your `oneInput` is compiled to a class field of type `FSharpFunc<_>`, and hence its type.

You can actually achieve same effect (i.e. turn true method into value) even without currying, very simply:

```
> let twoInputs x y =
>     let sum = x + y
>     let product a = sum * a
>     product

> let twoInputsAgain = twoInputs

val twoInputs : x:int -> y:int -> (int -> int)
val twoInputsAgain : (int -> int -> int -> int)
```

This happens because CLR doesn't support the notion of "assigning a method", so F# has to compile this by declaring `twoInputsAgain` as a field of type `FSharpFunc<_>` and then assigning to it an instance of a class that inherits from `FSharpFunc<_>` and calls `twoInputs` when `Invoke`d.

If you decompile it to C# (I use ILSpy), this is what you see:

```
static $Program()
{
    $Program.twoInputsAgain@11 = new Program.twoInputsAgain@11();
}

internal class twoInputsAgain@11 : OptimizedClosures.FSharpFunc<int, int, FSharpFunc<int, int>>
{
    public override FSharpFunc<int, int> Invoke(int x, int y)
    {
        return Program.twoInputs(x, y);
    }
}
```

In conclusion, I want to note that this disctinction doesn't matter very much in practice, unless you practice some really dark magic, so you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Very lucid answer, thank you! Can you recommend an F# book that dives into such details?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very much into books these days, since there is so much information online for free. For beginner F#-ers, I would highly recommend Scott Wlaschin's http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com, and for more in-depth material there is a lot, but one thing I will mention is Tomas Petricek's blog.